# VisualStudio - How do i automatically create accessors for base class functions when base class is in another assembly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have the following setup. A solution with 3 Projects.

Project A, Namespace A, Class A

Project B, Namespace B, Class B : A

and a Test project for unit tests on B. To access private functions of B i create an accessor in my Test project using *Create Private Accessor -> Test*.

It seems as A is in another assembly VS does not create accessor functions for A.

Comment: For private members? You can't access private members/methods of a base class.

Comment: Not for private members. Anyway also private members should be accessible for base class as stated here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/35b37c29-58f8-413e-b79d-4fcf16ae95a8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple accessors. Consider this:

```
// Assembly A
public class ClassA
{
    protected int someInt = 1;
    private void DoSthmWithA()
    {
        someInt = 10;
    }
}

// Assembly B
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    private void DoSthmWithB()
    {
        someInt = 11;
    }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void Testing
{
    var target = new ClassB();

    var poA = new PrivateObject(target, new PrivateType(typeof (ClassA)));
    var poB = new PrivateObject(target);

    var accA = new ClassA_Accessor(poA);
    var accB = new ClassB_Accessor(poB);
    accA.DoSthmWithA();
    Assert.AreEqual(accA.someInt, 10);
    accB.DoSthmWithB();
    Assert.AreEqual(accA.someInt, 11);
}
```

or

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Testing
{
   var target = new ClassB();

   var poA = new PrivateObject(target, new PrivateType(typeof(ClassA)));
   var poB = new PrivateObject(target);

   poA.Invoke("DoSthmWithA");

   var accA = new ClassA_Accessor(poA);
   Assert.AreEqual(accA.someInt, 10);

   poB.Invoke("DoSthmWithB");

   Assert.AreEqual(accA.someInt, 11);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution to me